# Apache RewriteRule regex with dots and requesting root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`DocumentRoot` points to a folder containing only .htaccess with `RewriteRule` directive.

A dot character in Apache regex matches any single character.

The rule `RewriteRule a..b - [G]` works as expected:

```
GET /ab HTTP/1.1
GET /axb HTTP/1.1
GET /axxxb HTTP/1.1
GET /zaxx HTTP/1.1
404 Not Found - OK

GET /axxb HTTP/1.1
GET /zaxxbz HTTP/1.1
410 Gone - OK
```

The rule `RewriteRule .. - [G]` works as expected too in every case except when requesting "/":

```
GET /x HTTP/1.1
404 Not Found - OK

GET /xx HTTP/1.1
GET /xxx HTTP/1.1
GET /xxxx HTTP/1.1
410 Gone - OK

GET / HTTP/1.1
410 Gone - WRONG!
```

Why the regex containing only dots does not work as expected when requesting "/" in Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule .. - [G]
```

Returns `410` for `/` because of `DirectoryIndex` directives that run before `mod_rewrite` module and append `index.html` or `index.*` in front of `/`.

That makes `..` match 2 characters of `index.html` and you get `410 Gone`.

If you disable this directive by placing this line at the top of your `.htaccess` then `410` will disappear for `/` URI:

```
DirectoryIndex ""
```